# Identification Technique

Tags: wireless, communication, identification, rfid, nfc

I'm building a 20cm x 20cm table that is divided into cells, it has 4 rows and 4 columns.
There will be different external blocks that have numbers, each block can stand on a single cell, each block has different number.

each cell on the table should be able to detect and recognize different blocks, so that i could know which block on which cell ...

The problem is, what technique can I ably inside the table/matrix to detect and identify these blocks so that, for instance, i know that the block with the number 5 is on the 3rd cell.

I'm thinking of NFC technology where each cell will has NFC reader and inside each block will be NFC tag but it's not practical due to the size and cost of the reader. any suggestions (it could be wired or wireless technique )?

[image: Matrix and Blocks.]

Thank you in advance,

Comment: *inspired by my little sons toy*. You can have a matrix of contacts on the board, while each block will have contacts on it with different configurations. Update: [This toy](http://www.amazon.com/Melissa-Doug-Farm-Sound-Blocks/dp/B00009WBWK)

Comment: Similar to @EugeneSh.'s comment - but you could have a pattern of black and white spots / squares which you read with an array of retroreflective detectors. More fiddly, more expensive, but means that you won't have contacts to clean, if that's an issue.

Comment: If you allow a contact solutiuon, you can give each block a pair of contacts (concentrical) with a unique resistance. Or even put a small microchip inside that can identify itself when queried.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the possibility of walls or the detection on the ground, every block would know where it is. So the only thing left is a wireless communication; with radio or visual (laser, blinking led, infrared).

If not here some ideas to track the other cubes:

1. Camera (e.g. Barcodes or LEDs for Identification) -> Complicated
2. Triangulation with external radios (like GPS) -> Expensive
3. RFID (more distance than just nfc) -> Expensive
4. Laser Sensors -> I think expensive
5. Radio running time -> Hard and Complicated
6. Ultrasonic -> Cheap and Easy

I think the best are Ultrasonic Sensors, there is a cheap one for the Arduino board. Ultrasonic Sensors normally have a Trigger Pin and an 'Answer' Pin. The Time between Trigger and Answer is proportional to the distance and under 10ms for a small board (<1m), so in a while with delays the distance can be measured easy with a convenient microcontroller. The problem here is that your boxes need openings for the sensors (2 holes for each).

Answer (score 0):

There are no doubt many solutions to this problem (and this is a little too big to get into a comment)- I offer mine based upon a **sort of** QR code.

**ON each block**:

Paint the sides of each block with a grid code. As the block can be placed in any one of four orientations you will need to identify which way it is. QR code uses large corner blocks. Paint is cheap (or you could just print up some sticky squares and apply them)

Here's an example of the idea

[image]

On the board paint large black areas so each grid location can be identified.

When a block is placed onto the grid the large identification square will identify which grid space is occupied.

Now the difficult bit. The sensor will be a fixed camera (a £5 web cam?) placed above the board, The image can then be analysed in terms of which grid locations are occupied/empty and if occupied what is the encoding number of the block. You might be able to do the analysis with a raspberry pi or something similar.